# Go to definition in different file in vim

Tags: vim, lisp

I'm using slimv to create a small common lisp project. I would like a way to jump to the definition of a function I defined in another file. Is there a way to do that?'

Comment: `gd` should work if Vim recognizes that filetype.

Comment: `gd` works only if the definition is in the same file. What do you mean by recognizing the file type? Code completion and syntax highlighting work.

Comment: Under `:help gd` it points to `:help include-search` which points to `:help 'include'`.  You may want to review these help sections, especially the last one.  If you have filetype plugins enabled I would have assumed that the `'include'` option would have been properly configured for you, though.

Comment: So the problems seems to be that you don't explicitly include files in lisp. They are listed in the package definition. No idea how to solve this though. Thanks for showing how to find the explanation:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net). It supports lisp.

After you generate a tags file you can use `<C-]>` to jump to the definition. Take a look at `:h tags`